# How to pass variable in a project file to the "MSBuild" task

Tags: msbuild, mono, xbuild

We are using a project file, which then calls MSBuild task. For example,

```
<Target Name="Clean">
  <MSBuild Targets="Clean" Projects="@(Solution)"/>
</Target>
```

In the project file I now define a variable which I want to pass to MSBuild task.

Comment: Found it myself:
You can Pass Properties with: Properties="aa=true"

Comment: It might help to know that the elements with arbitrary names inside `Target` elements are called tasks. So, your question is about the _"MSBuild task"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself!
This works:

```
<Target Name="Clean">
  <MSBuild Targets="Clean" Projects="@(Solution)" Properties="Key=Value"/>
</Target>
```